# How and where can I define and call a function (php) in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have this function:

```
    function functionName($url){
       $image_url = parse_url($url);
       if($image_url['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' || $image_url['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
          echo 'It's youtube!'
       }
    }
```

Now, I have a view and I want to call it in a Global:PHP field.

**1- Where do i have to put the function? I need to create a module?

2- How to call this function in the global:PHP field. Something like a import?**

Sorry, im starting with drupal...
Thanks so much! :)

Comment: The best way would be to create a field formatter module. It is generally frowned upon to use the global PHP field. To best answer this question, we would probably want to know what the final outcome you want is (I am assuming in the end you don't just want the its youtube string). You could put the function in a module and call the function in the Global:PHP field though. If your module is enabled, you just call the function, no need for any "import"s

Comment: If you tell us what the final outcome you want is, we may be able to suggest a module that already does it or a better solution.

Comment: thanks so match! i want to use a function to obtain the thumbnail in vimeo. i did a function and i just call the function and works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function is in every module in views .
just use name of function and pass value to it !

Answer (score 0):

If you define the function in a .module file, you can call it from any other .module file or any other file where you write PHP code in (like php classes or .inc file in Drupal 7) or probably even the theme - yourtheme.theme file (drupal 8) or template.php (drupal 7).

You should call the function from within a certain context, like inside a hook function (which still exist in drupal 8). For example [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7.x) -- which is automatically invoked every time an entity is 'inserted'.

There are [many other hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/group/hooks/7.x) that exist -- check them out.